# Selecting Multiple Buttons by Sliding Finger Over Them

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, controls, uicontrol

I'm trying to make it so that the buttons I have are selected whenever a finger passes over them on the screen. These buttons were added with fast enumeration (there are 20 of them), so I'm unsure of how exactly to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are various different properties on UIButton that you can use to achieve this.  In particular what comes to mind is the isHighlighted and isSelected properties of the button.  These are states on the button that you can manipulate to achieve the visual solution, and disable and enable the buttons as you want to make them press-able by the user.  Also be sure to use the correct UIControlState you want.  As in TouchUp, TouchDown etc...